# Not able to locate the animations folder in ngx-spinner folder in node_modules

Tags: angular, angular12, ngx-spinner

Hi I am working on an angular project below mentioned are the version details of the same.

- Angular v12
- ngx-spinner v12

I am not able to locate the animations folder inside the ngx-spinner library in node_modules folder.

I have included the css file link in angular.json file

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",  
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css"
            ]
```

I used the command to install the ngx-spinner

```
npm i ngx-spinner@12.0.0
```

but the animations folder doesn't seem to exist in the node_modules folder below is a screenshot of the same

[image: screenshot]

Can you please let me know what could be the problem here

Comment: I just tested a nom install of the ngx-spinner and it was version 14.0.0 installed. I found the path you are looking for so I guess you just should use the newer version.
`npm i ngx-spinner`

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. When installed with npm, it did not create the animations folder, just like you did. I first installed yarn with the command npm install -g yarn. After installing ngx-spinner with yarn command, it created animations folder. yarn add ngx-spinner

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://gitter.im/ngx-spinner/community and the creator of the package make sure if your using older version of ngx-spinner(below v13) then you don't need to add css in angular.json file. So you don't need the reference nor the files in the version you are using. So delete the
"node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css" from angular.json